# AngularJS empty input model after mvc postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Using AngularJS with ng-model all my fields are cleared after postback from mvc controllers. Can prevent this somehow and put the values from the postback into the model? Every time the user make a postback with an validation error all fields get cleared because of the ng-model. Any ideas?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Register.Username, new { @ng_model = "username" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Register.Password, new { @ng_model = "password" })
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel viewModel)
{
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because when Angular kicks in, values for username and password on **$scope** are null and they would override what is set by your view.

ng-init may solve your problem

consider something like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Register.Username, new { @ng_model = "username", @ng_init = "username ='" + Model.Register.Username + "'" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Register.Password, new { @ng_model = "password", @ng_init = "password ='" + Model.Register.Password + "'" })
```

Cheers

Comment: This will not work if a Model value contains un-escaped quote characters.